# JAVA Windows Registry vs UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, windows, exception, registry, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I try to modify Win7 registry. In IDEA I've no errors, but when I use the console I have UnsatisfiedLinkError exception:

```
Exception in Thread main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper.RegOpenKey(ILjava/lang/String;I)[I at com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper.RegOpenKey(Native Method) at
com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegSetValueEx(UnknownSource) at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:13)
```

code

```
import com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegSetValueEx(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Keyboard Layout\\Toggle", "Hotkey" , "2");
            WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegSetValueEx(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Keyboard Layout\\Toggle", "Language Hotkey" , "2");
            WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegSetValueEx(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Keyboard Layout\\Toggle", "Layout Hotkey" , "1");
        }
    }

}
```